# Find by xpath table without id, name and class. Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

[the HTML TAG HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUraL.png)

Here is the *HTML* about my problem, I am pretty new in *xpath*... I just want to create a *xpath* in c# wherein i will click the clock in and clock out button. I know my question is basic but im having a hard time figuring out.

here is the *HTML*

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><img height="1" src="/images/px.gif" width="10"></td>
            <td align="left">
                <table cellspacing="4" class="btn" onmousedown=
                "return sbtnDown(this);" onmouseout="sbtnOut(this)"
                onmouseover="sbtnOver(this)" onmouseup=
                "timeSheetAction2(&quot;TIME_SHEET_PUNCH&quot;,&quot;&quot;,&quot;IN&quot;,true)"
                width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src="/images/20x20/clock_go.png"></td>
                            <td align="left" nowrap width="100%">Clock In</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td><img height="1" src="/images/px.gif" width="40"></td>
            <td align="center">
                <table cellspacing="4" class="btn" onclick=
                "window.showPopUp_Lookup({&quot;center&quot;:1,&quot;w&quot;:780,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Change Cost Centres&quot;,&quot;singleValue&quot;:1,&quot;h&quot;:800,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;/ta/6118466.admin?rnd=EYH&amp;@impl=zeyt.ta.ui.time.UiControl_ChangeCostCenters&amp;@windowId=QLYTJ&amp;Ext=login&amp;sft=PYPBHDQTFA&amp;@showStackMB=0&amp;@pushOnStack=0&amp;@noBG=1&amp;MyLookupName=CHANGE_COST_CENTERS&amp;which_cc_can_change=1&quot;,&quot;fName&quot;:&quot;z230&quot;});return false;"
                onmousedown="sbtnDown(this)" onmouseout="sbtnOut(this)"
                onmouseover="sbtnOver(this)" width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input name="z230" onchange=
                            "this.chkChng=0;timeSheetAction2(&quot;TIME_SHEET_PUNCH&quot;, this.value, &quot;CHANGE_CC&quot;, true);"
                            type="hidden"><img src=
                            "/images/20x20/clock_refresh.png"></td>
                            <td align="left" nowrap width="100%">Change Department</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td><img height="1" src="/images/px.gif" width="40"></td>
            <td align="right">
                <table cellspacing="4" class="btn" onmousedown=
                "sbtnDown(this)" onmouseout="sbtnOut(this)" onmouseover=
                "sbtnOver(this)" onmouseup=
                "timeSheetAction2(&quot;TIME_SHEET_PUNCH&quot;,&quot;&quot;,&quot;OUT&quot;,true)"
                width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src=
                            "/images/20x20/clock_cancel.png"></td>
                            <td align="left" nowrap width="100%">Clock Out</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here are the method I've already tried but still no luck...

```
browser.FindElementsByXPath("//td[contains(., 'Clock In')]");

browser.FindElementsByXPath("//id('PAGE_BODY')/x:table[1]/x:tbody/x:tr/x:td[2]/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr/x:td[2]"); #I got this xpath using xpather a firefox plugin
```

Comment: Post your attempts pls

Comment: I have tried this method below

browser.FindElementsByXPath("//td[contains(., 'Clock In')]");

browser.FindElementsByXPath("//id('PAGE_BODY')/x:table[1]/x:tbody/x:tr/x:td[2]/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr/x:td[2]");  <-- I use xpather to get this xpath..

Still no luck... :(

Comment: edit your post with that code @Noel Manarang

Comment: @AndreL thanks for guiding me, I am pretty new in stackoverflow mate thanks!

Comment: What URL? I already attached a image... [the HTML TAG HERE]..

Comment: Where is the _clock in and clock out button_?

Comment: Please go ahead and post the HTML in your question. At some point in the future the image will no longer exist and this question will be much less valuable.

Comment: The td with align left is the Clock In button, td with align right is the Clock out button, its hard because it is wrap in a table....

Comment: @NoelManarang - If you provide us an incomplete input, we won't be able to provide you a solution. In developer console, right click on the table tag and select _Edit as HTML_. Copy that code and paste it in the question by editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should solve it.

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("btn")).click(); // For "Clock In"
driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("btn"))[2].click(); // For "Clock Out"
```

Clicking on the table for *Clock In* and *Clock Out* will suffice since it has events like `onmouseup`, `onmousedown` and so on. It's not necessary to select the `td` tag containing the text "Clock In" or "Clock Out".

Comment: Thanks for that but i encountered some error 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException'...

Comment: Try this `xpath("//table[@class='btn'][1]").click()` This should click on _Clock In_. I'm assuming that only those 3 tables have the class `btn`.

Comment: Thanks @jason but still no luck.

Comment: Can you send me the complete page source?

Comment: Where could i possibly send it?

Comment: Use pastebin.com and once you save it post the link here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/77fWVSvT hope this helps. Thank you very much for the effort..

Comment: Is it necessary to use xPath?

Comment: Cause this should work for you `driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("btn")).click();` for _Clock In_.

Comment: And this for _Clock Out_ `driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("btn"))[2].click();`

Comment: @NoelManarang - Let me know if you still face an issue with this.

Comment: Hi For the clock in xpath i didnt have an error but the it didnt click the button

as for the clock out i had an error here is my code

browser.FindElementByClassName("btn")[2].Click();

Comment: @NoelManarang - There is a spelling mistake `browser.FindElementsByClassName("btn")[2]`. Make sure there is a `s` in `Elements`.

Comment: Hi @jason sorry the clock in work!! 

but the clock out seem to have an syntax error...

Comment: @NoelManarang - Oh good. I guess then the spelling mistake should fix _Clock Out_ issue. Check my previous comment.

Comment: It did work while breakpoint is running, but when w/out breakpoint the code doesn't work...

Comment: Does it throw an Exception? What is the exception? And on which line does that occur?

Comment: No exception @jayson... here my is code.. 

http://pastebin.com/PSDSsVfK hope it helps

Comment: Solved by using Thread.Sleep(1); then browser.Navigate().Refresh(); after button click. Thanks mate..

Comment: Instead of `Thread.sleep(1)`, you should use waits in selenium. Check out this doc [link](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits).